# CSS not loading with node.js and express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

My CSS won't load when running my HTML. The HTML is hooked up correctly with the CSS but express and node.js seem to be ignoring it. I can't understand the articles and tutorials or other stack overflow questions so I'll just send the code.

I also get an error that says the MIME-type is text/HTML even though I've checked multiple times, the MIME-type is indeed text/CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Infinite Road</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="infinite">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background: radial-gradient(#9bdfff, #009be4);
  }
  .infinite {
      position: relative;
      width: 800px;
      height: 160px;
      background: #525252;
      transform-origin: bottom;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(30deg);
  }
  .infinite::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 0%, #fff 70%, #525252 70%, #525252 100%);
      background-size: 120px;
      animation: animate 0.5s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
      0% {
          background-position: 0px;
      }
      100% {
          background-position: -120px;
      }
  }
  .infinite::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: #333;
      bottom: -30px;
      transform-origin: top;
      transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(-25deg)
  }
  .shadow {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -93px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      width: 95%;
      height: 60px;
      background: linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
      opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

**JS:**

```
const path = require('path');
const { readFile } = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))
});

app.get('/', (request, responseC) => {
    responseC.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "style.css"))
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log('App availible on http://localhost:8080'))
```

Stackoverflow told me there's too much code, not enough text so I tried to add more.

Comment: On Stack Overflow the questions have to be self-contained. That means the question must have all necessary information to be answerable.

Comment: What can I add? Sorry, I was having trouble formatting the code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] direct in your code.

Comment: I will edit it for that. Hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: You have same routes. The second should be `app.get('/style.css', (request, responseC) => {`

Comment: OMFL it just worked and I did that before. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
app.get('/', (request, responseC) => {`
```

to

```
app.get('/style.css', (request, responseC) => {
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

create a folder with name "public" in your project root directory and use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

or

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

if you have done everything right then you can access file like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
```

css link

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: you can also look at official express documentation https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I already found a solution. I messed up and just did "/" in my app.get. The answer above by me is the correct one and I need to wait 1 more day to mark it as correct.

Comment: This is correct way to serve static files in node.js. BlitzDBS's answer is not so commonly used.

Comment: I followed a fireship video and I got this from a comment on the original question.